# Why Is My Code Not Removing Whitespace Of String?

Tags: ios, string, uitableview, removing-whitespace

I have a `UITableView` that displays a list of users. If their `display_name` is `null` in the returned JSON, then their `socialNetworkHandle` is displayed instead. However, I am having trouble trying to figure out why some users are left with their `displayName` containing spaces at the beginning of the string when I have set the spaces to be trimmed.

First is the struct to hold the user's information:

```swift
internal struct UserInformation {

    let socialNetworkHandle: String
    var displayName: String? = nil

    internal init?(socialNetworkHandle: String, displayName: String? = nil) {
        self.socialNetworkHandle = socialNetworkHandle
        self.displayName = displayName
    }

}
```

Next is the code where I parse the JSON to create a struct of the user's information:

```swift
private func userInformation(from jsonDictionary: JSONDictionary) -> FeedwallPost.UserInformation? {

    // ...Some parsing code...

    var userInformation = Post.UserInformation()

    if let displayName = jsonDictionary["display_name"] as? String {
        userInformation?.displayName = displayName
    } else {
        print("`displayName` is not of type `String`")
    }

    // ...Some parsing code...

    return userInformation

}
```

Finally, I display the user's `displayName` or `socialNetworkHandle` in the cell. If the `displayName` is `nil`, then the `socialNetworkHandle` is displayed:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    /// ...Cell configuration code...

    cell.textLabel?.text = post.userInformation.displayName?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) ?? post.userInformation.socialNetworkHandle.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    /// ... Cell configuration code...


    return cell

}
```

The problem that I keep encountering is that users are being displayed with spaces at the beginning of their `displayName` when I have trimmed it for display. The following screenshot illustrates what is happening:

[image: Screenshot of iPhone displaying users]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: You want the answer made in Objc or Swift?

Answer (score 1):

This is the `Objc` Code, this is a category for `NSString` class

### Objective-C

```
#import "NSString+CustomTrimming.h"

@implementation NSString (CustomTrimming)

/***
 Remove unnecesary spaces between the words, ex: @"asd      asdasdas"
 */
- (NSString*)stringRemovingUnnecessarySpaces
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@" +" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:self options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length]) withTemplate:@" "];
    newString = [newString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    return newString;
}
```

This is the same category for swift

### Swift

```
import UIKit

extension String{

    func removingUnnecesarySpaces() ->String
    {  do
    {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: " +", options: NSRegularExpression.Options(rawValue: UInt(0)))
        var newString = regex .stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions.init(rawValue: 0), range: NSMakeRange(0, self.characters.count), withTemplate: " ")
        newString = newString.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
        return newString
    }
    catch
    {

    }
        return self
    }
}
```

with this examples

```
    debugPrint("  prueba     esto     ".removingUnnecesarySpaces())
    debugPrint(" prueba esto     ahora".removingUnnecesarySpaces())
```

the console log prints this

```
    "prueba esto"
    "prueba esto ahora"
```

in your specific case you only need replace your code with this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    /// ...Cell configuration code...

    cell.textLabel?.text = post.userInformation.displayName?.removingUnnecesarySpaces() ?? post.userInformation.socialNetworkHandle.removingUnnecesarySpaces()

    /// ... Cell configuration code...


    return cell

}
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: @Reiner Melian I like your solution! However, can you tell me why mine wasn't working?

Comment: @Reiner Melian I implemented your solution, but I am getting the same result as before the implementation.

Comment: Well can you send me your complete project to review it?, your original solution don't work because the `method trimmingCharacters` remove only the spaces on the beginig and the end of the string, best regards, my email is rmelian2014@gmail.com

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do. I just want to trim the leading and trailing spaces. I appreciate your help, but this project is for a company that I'm under contract with, so I'm not able to share it.

Comment: Try using the method when you are creating your model, and you can debug before and after the method work, check also your constraints in your cell and your label horizontal aligment, Iam pretty sure that my method works, because I use this in many projects now